# PictureBox doesn't land on correct coordinates

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop

So I am trying to move a pictureBox onto a panel. The problem is that the picturebox doesn't land on to the coordinate of the mouse but instead someplace else.

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.DoDragDrop(pictureBox1,DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }

    private void panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;

    }

    private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(e.X,e.Y);
    }
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.X` and `e.Y` represent screen coordinates and it seems you're looking for client coordinates.

```
pictureBox1.Location = panel1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
```

Comment: OMG so many technicalities. I don't know how can you guys who answer questions on SO remember so many fine points. Anyways real thanks to you.

Comment: You're welcome! (A lot of it is down to having experienced similar issues before :D)